# Objective C - Call method in a view controller which is already in top of navigation from app delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

Say that I have to call a method in a View Controller (which is the one shown to the user at the top) from App Delegate, after receiving a silent push notification. The so-called method in return has to show an alert, and after customer clicks on alert view button, the view controller has to be popped out.

My problem is that the `clickedButtonAtIndex` method in not getting fired after the button is clicked. What is the reason for that?

**AppDelegate.m**

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    TestViewController *test = [[TestViewController alloc] init];
    [test showAlert];
}
```

**TestViewController.h**

```
@interface TestViewController : BaseViewController<UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

**TestViewController.m**

```
-(void)showAlert {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Show Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    alert.tag = 100;
    [alert show];
}
```

Comment: In our AppDelegate you create a new instance of the view controller (i.e. now you have two instances, one that is actually being displayed and the new one). Then  you call showAlert, which creates an alert view and displays it. Then the method ends and your newly created instance `test` goes out of scope and gets deallocated.

You need to call showAlert on the instance that is actually being displayed and you need to find a way to have a reference to that instance  available in your AppDelegate.

Comment: UIAlertView is deprecated btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to access the existing top view controller instance, not instantiate a new one as you're doing.
The way to do that depends on how your app interface is defined: for example if you are using a navigation controller you'll have to access the top item of its viewControllers array.